# Android URL Underscore is working for new versions

Tags: android, url, android-volley

**Description**

I'm using volley to get a json string request from my server. It's working fine for my Galaxy S6 Edge (Android 5.1.1, API 22), but not for my other phone (Android 4.2.2, API 17).

It works when I use other links without an underscore in subdomain.

```
subdomain_v2.website.de
```

But I want to get the JSON string for my old phone too.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

**EDIT**

I don't even know if the problem is there, but as I said its working fine for my edge.

Maybe this can help you, the error printstack of volley.

```
10-14 11:50:19.942  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException: http://subdomain_v2.website.de/api/?function=all
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: http://subdomain_v2.website.de/api/?function=all
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.<init>(HttpConnection.java:304)
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:495)
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110)
10-14 11:50:19.952  26144-26144/de.my_example.appv20 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
```

Comment: No answer? Please I need it for today.

Comment: This is a community forum, people will help if they feel like it, its not a support tool for anyone or any company

Answer (score 0):

From the logcat: `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException:`, and from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/UnknownHostException.html)

> Thrown when a hostname can not be resolved.

Accessing from my browser, the host responds `"NetworkError: 503 Service 
Unavailable - http://subdomain_v2.website.de/api/?function=all"`

Comment: Thanks, but I keep the URL secret that I use. From my browser it shows me a content with JSON strings. So, it works fine for my new version of Android,

Comment: UnknownHostException exceptions are not related to details in the URI, they are usually some miscoordination with the IP adress of the host. Locally, I cannot check what you meant, but the fake server `http://subdomain_v2.website.de` trully is fake, and will never work. Either give us the real host, or ping from your machine, check that the DNS is correct, and use that IP on your program.